# Can I connect git if I downloaded the code as zip

Tags: git, cloning

I downloaded the latest code of a repositiry as zip but now I want to be able to work with branches too.

Is there anyway I can use the folder as a git repository just like what I have if I clone the project?

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue.

TL;DR short version relevant commands:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:somecompany/some-repo.git
git add .
git pull origin master
```

Full story: I was having trouble cloning the repo so I eventually downloaded and expanded the zip instead.  I did `git init` after which `git status` showed:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
    .rspec
    .ruby-version
    ...(all the directories of the project)...

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Then I added the origin with
`git remote add origin git@github.com:somecompany/some-repo.git`

I did a `git fetch` which got the remote's branches info.

When I did `git pull origin master` it said:

```
From github.com:somecompany/some-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    .gitignore
    .rspec
    .ruby-version
    ...(all the files of the project)...
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I tried several things that didn't help, finally I did:

`git add .`

the files were all staged now but I did NOT make a commit.  Instead I did:

`git pull origin master` which output:

```
From github.com:somecompany/some-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Now when I did `git status` it reported:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And I was good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You have to first initialize the folder as a GIT repo and then add the remote. For example:

```
cd folder
git init .
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

And then resync with **git pull**.

Comment: however, once run `git pull`, it looks like doing `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git` and very slow. The whole point of downloading the zip and then add the remote origin is to avoid the slow downloading using `git clone https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

It is something like you created a local repo in your m/c and then want to push it to github

The github repo for your project has already been created on github.

Either you have created it or has been added as one of the collaborators in your case for downloaded repository code

When you create a project

```
$ rails new app1 --skip-active-record --skip-bundle
```

and want this to be associated to the repo

cd to the project folder,

```
$ cd app1
```

and then execute
   $git init
   $ git remote add origin git@github.com:analytics/app1.git

then do

```
$git pull origin master
$git push
```

So, the local repo has been pushed to the remote github repo

Answer (score -1):

You can paste git config file and set remote URL properly. You can start pull push. happy coding