# Azure DevOps Git Repo Error - RPC failed; curl 56 Failure

Tags: git, curl, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps project with a couple of Git repos.  When I do a `git clone` from a Command Prompt on the "bad" repo I get the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'myBadRepo'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 176 objects to send. (0 ms)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
Receiving objects: 100% (176/176), 10.22 MiB | 25.46 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (48/48), done.
```

Searching Google for `curl 56 Failure` mostly says that this is an issue with a firewall or proxy.  I am on a corporate network, using Cisco AnyConnect as a VPN, but turning that off makes no difference.  My machine is also using zScaler for "Internet Security" which I know  is messing with the certificates, but I cannot disable it.  But I doubt that the firewall, proxy or certs are main the issue, because I can successfully clone a different Git repo from the same Azure DevOps organization and project:

```
Cloning into 'myWorkingRepo'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 107 objects to send. (3 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (107/107), 859.57 KiB | 29.64 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), done.
```

I have tried doing a "shallow clone" as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207817/11057678 and increasing the http.postBuffer as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68097529/11057678 but neither makes any differece.

I turned on verbose mode and tracing, as suggested at https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-clone-fails-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-693897332.html

```
set GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
set GIT_TRACE=1
set GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

I can see that both logs have repeated warnings of `Info: schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data` which is concerning, but the "working" repo is cloning successfully, while the "bad" repo has a lot more of these warnings, and after the last set of 647 (!) `failed to decrypt` messages it shows a closed connection and then the curl 56 Failure:

```
Info: schannel: server closed abruptly (missing close_notify)
Info: Closing connection 0
channel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with dev.azure.com port 443
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Excerpts from the "bad" log is below (the full log is too long to post).  Both logs contain the same authorization-related warning and errors, which are not however preventing a clone of the "good" repo.  One error in particular is the URL-encoded

```
The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource
```

Where is this user aaaaaaa coming from?  I suspect that if I can configure Git and/or the Azure DevOps repo in a way to eliminate these authorization-related warnings and errors, my problems with the "bad" repo will be solved.  Hopefully someone can take a look at them and give me some advice or direction, thanks!

"Bad" repo log excerpts:

```
git clone https://myOrganization@dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo

05:13:49.157466 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
05:13:49.158466 git.c:459               trace: built-in: git clone https://myOrganization@dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo
Cloning into 'myBadRepo'...
05:13:49.180609 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git remote-https origin https://myOrganization@dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo
05:13:49.194684 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
05:13:49.195683 git.c:748               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://myOrganization@dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo
05:13:49.196685 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://myOrganization@dev.azure.com/myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo
05:13:49.212111 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
05:13:49.220376 http.c:689              == Info: Couldn't find host dev.azure.com in the (nil) file; using defaults
05:13:49.225816 http.c:689              == Info:   Trying 13.107.42.20:443...
05:13:49.244824 http.c:689              == Info: Connected to dev.azure.com (13.107.42.20) port 443 (#0)
05:13:49.245003 http.c:689              == Info: schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
05:13:49.313976 http.c:636              => Send header, 0000000240 bytes (0x000000f0)
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: GET /myOrganization/myDevOpsProject/_git/myBadRepo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: Host: dev.azure.com
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: User-Agent: git/2.36.0.windows.1
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: Accept: */*
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br, zstd
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: Pragma: no-cache
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header: Git-Protocol: version=2
05:13:49.313976 http.c:648              => Send header:
05:13:49.571301 http.c:689              == Info: schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
... 8 lines removed ...
05:13:49.672466 http.c:689              == Info: schannel: failed to decrypt data, need more data
05:13:49.672466 http.c:689              == Info: Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000027 bytes (0x0000001b)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
[....]
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/cc808ba9-3e5f-4f13-a70b-5b65bf454995
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000071 bytes (0x00000047)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="https://tfsprodcus6.visualstudio.com/"
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000033 bytes (0x00000021)
[...]
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000059 bytes (0x0000003b)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-TFS-FedAuthRealm: https://tfsprodcus6.visualstudio.com/
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000059 bytes (0x0000003b)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-TFS-FedAuthIssuer: https://dev.azure.com/myOrganization/
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000073 bytes (0x00000049)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-VSS-AuthorizationEndpoint: https://vssps.dev.azure.com/myOrganization/
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000060 bytes (0x0000003c)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-VSS-ResourceTenant: cc808ba9-3e5f-4f13-a70b-5b65bf454995
05:13:49.672466 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000710 bytes (0x000002c6)
05:13:49.672466 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-TFS-SoapException: %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%3Csoap%3AEnvelope%20xmlns%3Asoap%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F05%2Fsoap-envelope%22%3E%3Csoap%3ABody%3E%3Csoap%3AFault%3E%3Csoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3Esoap%3AReceiver%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3Csoap%3ASubcode%3E%3Csoap%3AValue%3EUnauthorizedRequestException%3C%2Fsoap%3AValue%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ASubcode%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ACode%3E%3Csoap%3AReason%3E%3Csoap%3AText%20xml%3Alang%3D%22en%22%3ETF400813%3A%20The%20user%20%27aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa%27%20is%20not%20authorized%20to%20access%20this%20resource.%3C%2Fsoap%3AText%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AReason%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AFault%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3ABody%3E%3C%2Fsoap%3AEnvelope%3E
05:13:49.673499 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000148 bytes (0x00000094)
05:13:49.673499 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-TFS-ServiceError: TF400813%3A%20The%20user%20%27aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa%27%20is%20not%20authorized%20to%20access%20this%20resource.
05:13:49.673499 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000079 bytes (0x0000004f)
05:13:49.673499 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-VSS-S2STargetService: 00000002-0000-8888-8000-000000000000/visualstudio.com
05:13:49.673499 http.c:636              <= Recv header, 0000000540 bytes (0x0000021c)
05:13:49.673499 http.c:648              <= Recv header: X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect: https://spsprodcus4.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signin?realm=dev.azure.com&reply_to=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.azure.com%2FmyOrganization%2FmyDevOpsProject%2F_git%2FmyBadRepo%2Finfo%2Frefs%3Fservice%3Dgit-upload-pack&redirect=1&hid=73b36635-d080-433b-9d64-87b14cd2b062&context=eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiOWE0OWZlYjMtY2FkYS00YWRmLWFkMjItZWZiZWViYWY0NDdhIiwicXMiOnt9LCJyciI6IiIsInZoIjoiIiwiY3YiOiIiLCJjcyI6IiJ90#ctx=eyJTaWduSW5Db29raWVEb21haW5zIjpbImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSIsImh0dHBzOi8vbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbSJdfQ2
```

Answer (score 14):

Following the suggestion and link from @Philippe, adding the zScaler certificate to my Git configuration solved my problem.  After reading through the posts, the exact steps I took were:

- From the Windows State Menu, run the “Manage Computer Certificates” control panel app
- Go to Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates -> Zscaler Root CA, right-click the certificate to Open it
- On the Details tab, click “Copy to File”
- The Certificate Export Wizard will open, click Next
- Select “Base-64 encoded X.509 (.cer)” and click Next
- Save the file as “C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\ZscalerRootCA.cer”, click Finish, and exit the control panel app
- Open the Command prompt and configure Git to use the certificate, by running the following commands:

```
- git config --global http.sslbackend openssl
- git config --global http.sslcainfo C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ZscalerRootCA.cer
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Steve. I followed these steps to pull from aws codecommit, but I'm getting this error:  fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo/': error setting certificate file: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\ZscalerRootCA.cer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

It's definitely a Zscaler issue.
I had exactly the same issue (the bigger is the repo, the higher is the probability to have the curl error but not always) and found the explanation in this [answer](https://community.zscaler.com/t/installing-tls-ssl-root-certificates-to-non-standard-environments/7261/26)

The only solution is to use the Zscaler certificate.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is this user `aaaaaaa` coming from?

It is (as illustrated in [`Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/master/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/team/credentials.py#L120=)) the `_ANONYMOUS_USER_ID`.

The error message just means an anonymous user cannot access this repository (which is expected).

Since even a shallow clone does not work, I would, for testing:

- do an [Azure pipeline](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/) to see if the sync source (ie the clone/pull) step works there
- or in a similar pipeline, get an `git archive` (HEAD commit content as a zip), in order to make a new Azure Devops repository and try to push that content to it: that would validate if something in that content is problematic. See [this as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60375772/6309).