Git clone error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
I'm trying to git clone a repo but nothing seems to work. Every time I get the same error:
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
I'm trying through git bash, it starts the cloning process, receive the objects but then I have this error.
Cloning into 'XXXXX'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 5125 objects to send. (127 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (5125/5125), 226.43 MiB | 21.13 MiB/s, done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
Resolving deltas: 100% (2355/2355), done.
A detail is that I'm working at the company environment, but I seem to have all the developer's authorizations in this computer, my team colleagues are not facing this issue.
We thought it could be some problem related to the size of the repository, so I've followed other posts from here, but it didnt work. I've tried for example:
git config http.postBuffer 524288000


and
git config --global core.compression 0
git clone --depth 1 <repo_URI>
git fetch --unshallow 
git pull --all


But I got the error on the git clone part

Are you using a (Zscaler?) proxy? If yes, maybe similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164519/717372

How long does it run before you get that error? cURL error 56 is a network receive error, and in many cases it's specifically a timeout.
