# How to ensure data integrity when Git error occurs: RPC failed: curl 56 failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: git, curl, proxy

From this issue: [RPC failed: curl 56 failure when receiving data from the peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206530/rpc-failed-curl-56-failure-when-receiving-data-from-the-peer)

I have the same issue, and like the OP I am not sure the clone completed 100% correctly. Is there a way for git to verify the integrity of the clone so that my local copy matches the remote? and if there is a discrepancy, can it pull the specific files that did not transfer correctly?

All of the Reponses just say I need to fix the proxy issue (and yes I am behind a corporate proxy), but barring that, Is there a git command to verify your local copy matches to remote?