# Git - How to reconnect an existing project (changes made) to an existing repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

I have a project that was connected to a git repo. Now I changed the machine. I downloaded the project on the new machine and made changes. Now I am trying to connect to the same repo and push the changes but can't. VS Code shows everything as U(untracked). I signed in to VS code through GitHub just like my previous machine, yet all the files are shown as "U". How do I push the changes?

Comment: When you copied the project, did you copy the full `.git` directory with it? Please explain more precisely what you mean by "downloaded".

Comment: Regardless, you could resort to a brute force approach: make a fresh clone on your new machine, and copy all the changed files into that fresh clone. While it's not the most elegant approach, it's certainly the simplest one to explain!

Comment: By downloaded, I mean downloaded the code as a zip file from github (you get an option there). And then started working in that folder.

Comment: Oh, I see. That download option is intended for when you want to use code but not modify it. If you want to modify it, you should do a `git clone` instead and copy the modified files into that sandbox.

Comment: But actually, this question has been asked several times on SO before. I think the accepted answer to this one could help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15681643/3216427 and maybe the top answer to this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354086/can-i-connect-git-if-i-downloaded-the-code-as-zip Backup your work before you start trying this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone git repository from its zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681643/how-to-clone-git-repository-from-its-zip)

Comment: Many more hits from SO at https://www.google.com/search?q=connect+downloaded+code+to+github

Comment: I used the brute force approach as suggested in your 2nd comment. You may post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to know my recommendation helped. I won't post it as an answer, though, because this really is a duplicate question and I'm likely to get downvoted for answering it instead of closing it. Such are the ways of SO...